# String gets mutated when saving to mysql via PHP using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, pdo

This is the sql:

`INSERT INTO stepup (target, body) VALUES ('http://test.com/dev-ws/events', '{"username":"Unknown","verb":"answer","object":"http:\/\/localhost\/elgg\/answers\/view\/42954\/q1","context":{"course":"42902","phase":"1","widget_type":"questions","activity_id":"95c48","widget_title":"Wonder moment"},"originalrequest":{"value":{"description":"<p>\u041f\u0440\u043e\u0443\u0447\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0435<\/p>","question_id":42954}},"starttime":"2015-03-26 17:28:57 +0100","endtime":"2015-03-26 17:28:57 +0100"}')`

then I do `$conn->exec($sql);`

but the actual content of `body` in the DB (mysql) is:

`"{\"username\":\"Unknown\",\"verb\":\"answer\",\"object\":\"http://localhost/elgg/answers/view/42954/q1\",\"context\":{\"course\":\"42902\",\"phase\":\"1\",\"widget_type\":\"questions\",\"activity_id\":\"95c48\",\"widget_title\":\"Wonder moment\"},\"originalrequest\":{\"value\":{\"description\":\"<p>u041fu0440u043eu0443u0447u0432u0430u043du0435</p>\",\"question_id\":42954}},\"starttime\":\"2015-03-26 17:28:57 +0100\",\"endtime\":\"2015-03-26 17:28:57 +0100\"}"`

So `\u` is replaced by `u` :(

What can I do.. I thought that by not "preparing" the SQL, this will stop happening...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are injecting JSON content into an SQL string literal in a query. You probably have SQL-injection security holes, which is a worse problem than `\u` sequences going missing.

You should use parameterised queries to avoid having to think about escaping rules. For example in PDO:

```
$url= 'http://test.com/dev-ws/events';
$json= '{"username":"Unknown","verb":"answer","object":"http://localhost/elgg/answers/view/42954/q1","context":{"course":"42902","phase":"1","widget_type":"questions","activity_id":"95c48","widget_title":"Wonder moment"},"originalrequest":{"value":{"description":"<p>\u041f\u0440\u043e\u0443\u0447\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0435</p>","question_id":42954}},"starttime":"2015-03-26 17:28:57 +0100","endtime":"2015-03-26 17:28:57 +0100"}';

$q= $db->prepare('INSERT INTO stepup (target, body) VALUES (?, ?)');
$q->bindParam(1, $url, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->bindParam(2, $json, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->execute();
```

Comment: OK great, thank you... this is the best solution... but you should correct the typo: `$q->bindParam(2, $json, PDO::PARAM_STR);` instead of `1`

Answer (score 1):

in postgre:

```
\uxxxx, \Uxxxxxxxx (x = 0 - 9, A - F)   16 or 32-bit hexadecimal Unicode character value
```

please check:
[String Constants with C-style Escapes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html)

Solve:
you can use \ or regexp_replace(c, '[^\]\(u\d{4})', '\\\1', 'g');

Comment: Ups, actually it's mysql... so there it's the same thing? I have to manually take care of this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use PDO->quote().

Visit http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php for more details

You might also want to read about NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES sql mode of MySQL

Comment: Thank you for this but "PDO::quote() *places quotes around the input string* (if required) and escapes special characters within the input string" because of these quotes it didn't insert the string in DB.. it escaped `\u` correctly but I only want that, not quoting... is it possible?